# Automatically including a file in all system verilog files

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I have adopted a bunch of .sv files from a colleague and each one fails to compile since it is missing the `defined environment variables stored in a file called "globals.sv". Adding the line

```
`include "globals.sv"
```

to the top of every file would work but is there a ModelSim command line tag that I can use to automatically include this file for every .sv at compile time? I have to re-run the files with a "globals2.sv" and "globals3.sv" and it would be much easier to be able to include all the files at once. I am imagining a command such as:

```
vlog -env_variables globals.sv -c *.sv
vlog -env_variables globals2.sv -c *.sv
```

that would compile each .sv file with the variable definitions in globals.sv.

Any help you could give would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest using a top-level systemverilog package. Then you would import the package in each file. That imported package would `include globals.sv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing for you to do would be to write a script that adds the `` `include globals.sv `` to the beginning of every *.sv file. Then the code would work on any simulator.

There is a `vlog` option called `-mfcu` which compiles all the files as if they were included into one big file (*M*ulti *F*ile *C*ompilation *U*nit). So you can do something like

```
vlog -mfcu globals.sv rtl/*.sv
vlog -mfcu globals2.sv tb/*.sv
```